# smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.9 Application-specific password required

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at\n5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor h22sm15927247pfv.25 - gsmtp')

Environment variable are set but does not work (even though it's the exact value).

- I have set the app password in google account, captcha is disabled
- I have set the env variables in .bashrc file
  `export EMAIL_USER='da24@gmail.com'`
- Comparison btw the `os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')` and the mail value string is True

I am trying to import this in config file, when I use harcoded values it worked fine, but use I use `os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')`, it stops working and throws this error.

Answer (score 23):

An app password is a 16-digit passcode that gives a less secure app or device permission to access your Google Account. App passwords can only be used with accounts that have 2-Step Verification turned on.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Use apps password such as **EMAIL_USER="example.com"** **EMAIL_PASSWORD="twtsxiraaxpcuhuyp"**. If you do not have a gmail apps password, create a new app with using generate password. Check your apps and passwords
https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords.
Good Luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Created an App password in google account. Passed the created password into the environment variables and it worked. Just replace the regular password with the app 16 digit app password.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately found the answer later, a reboot of Linux or the bashrc file reload is required .
Unless that happens the env won't register that .
Also using python console to set env variables does not work, even after reboot.

Comment: Good that you solved it! Please remember to mark your question as solved!

Answer (score 0):

I made it work thanks to @Muhammadalive answer and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67545932/how-can-i-send-a-reset-password-email-on-django). I will copy below my code because some people upvoted the Community Bot request for a more clear answer.

> I am currently in development. If after deployment I think an update to the answer is necessary I'll come back and edit it.

I am using [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) to avoid writing the password and the email inside my settings.py.

```py
# settings.py
from decouple import config

#
# ... More code
#

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_POST = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# EMAIL_HOST_USER is the email: 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
# EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD is the 16 digit 'app password': 'twexamplexpcuhuy'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
```

The file where I have the password and email is called ".env" and it looks like this:

```
# .env

#
# ... More code
#
EMAIL_HOST_USER = example@gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = twexamplexpcuhuy
```

###### Step by step:

1. [Turn on two steps verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) in your google account.
2. [Create an app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for your django application in your google account. It will be a 16 digit password, different to your google account password. Google gives it to you in fours like "twex ampl expc uhuy", but you will use it all together like "twexamplexpcuhuy".
3. Update your settings.py as per the code above, using your gmail account and your app password (**don't use your normal gmail password** - follow @Murad farajov answer).