# Django can not send mail but smtplib can

Tags: python, django, email

I was trying to use django's accounts system and configured some templates. When i tried to do password reset it said "SMTPRecipientsRefused at /accounts/password_reset/". But it works when i send an email with `smtplib`.

In django settings:

```py
# EMAIL
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.X.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "X@mydomain"
EMAIL_PASSWORD = "password"
```

And the error:

```
Exception Type: SMTPRecipientsRefused at /accounts/password_reset/
Exception Value: {'X@gmail.com': (450, b'4.7.1 We do not relay gmail.com')}
```

But i knew i used the same mail before with smtplib and tried again, and it worked.

```py
>>> import smtplib
>>> from email.message import EmailMessage
>>> mail_server = "mail.X.com"
>>> mail_username = "X@mydomain"
>>> mail_password = "password"
>>> mail_port = 587
>>> msg = EmailMessage()
>>> msg["Subject"] = "subject test"
>>> msg["From"] = mail_username
>>> msg["To"] = "X@gmail.com"
>>> server = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server, mail_port)
>>> server.login(mail_username, mail_password)
(235, b'2.7.0 Ok')
>>> server.send_message(msg)
{}
>>> server.quit()
(221, b'2.0.0 Bye')
```

I tried adding `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "X@mydomain"` to the `settings.py` but it didn't make any difference. 
I tried adding `EMAIL_USE_TLS=True` but it said:

```
SSLCertVerificationError at /accounts/password_reset/
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'mail.X.com'. (_ssl.c:1131)
```

Comment: Is this a self-hosted mail server, which you can modify the configuration, or do you outsource hosting your mail server?

Comment: @NickODeil, it is a mail that my company bought. Not self-hosted.

Comment: Have you tried changing `EMAIL_PASSWORD = "password"` for `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"`?

Comment: @Martin I just tried and it worked. Thank you very much. You can add an answer if you want to. One thing I don't understand, why it said 'We do not relay gmail.com' if there is a problem with password.

Comment: Hi @Battos, I'm glad it helped! I don't know exactly why that is the error. I proposed to change that line by comparing your code with [my working code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70261815/smtplib-smtpauthenticationerror-534-b5-7-9-application-specific-password-req/76833941#76833941) . If someone reads this could you please give us a hand to understand why is that error? What it calls my attention is that it doesn't raise an error like "*`EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` not provided*" - but again, I haven't studied it in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As replied previously in the comment, I proposed to change this line:

```
EMAIL_PASSWORD = "password"
```

For this line:

```
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"
```